# How to pass a prop received from child component to another in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

Here is my parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Parent extends Component {
    state={
        myData: ""
    }

    getDataOne=(data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({ myData: data });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponentOne onGetSearch={this.getDataOne} />
                <ChildComponentTwo dataOne={this.props.location.state.searchData} dataTwo={this.state.myData}  />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent;
```

This is how it goes.

- I've initially gotten data as a prop from the Component that redirected to this . That
  is the data called dataOne, I passed it to ChildComponentTwo.
- Then, I'm now trying to pass another data gotten from ChildComponentOne to ChildComponentTwo with another prop name called dataOne but it's returning empty string when trying to access it from ChildComponentTwo through this.props.

The only data I could access is dataOne.

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: did you check console logging the value of the state variable before sending it to the prop? whether it's set in the function

Comment: Yes, I did and it displays inside the Parent component but returns empty in ChildComponentTwo

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the rendering time

Comment: That's what I guess too, can you help with any trick to get it to work?

Comment: Sure, please check the answer, hope it'll work. I just rendered the first child earlier so it will spare some time to update the state before the second child is rendered

Comment: wait I just saw an extra closing bracket in your set state method, try removing it

Comment: I've removed it, it was a typo here, it's not in the code actually.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reproduce your issue in a sandbox and it seems you have an issue publishing your data from `ComponentOne`.

It seems to be working just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bush-rbfct?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Oh, I guess the situation there is quite different from mine in some ways, I can't really figure out...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the time it renders the components. First, the React DOM renders the parent component, and then it'll render both the first and second children components at the same time, so the updated state won't be visible to the second child, because it's already created before the state variable is set. try creating the first child component before the return as follows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Parent extends Component {
    state={
        myData: ""
    }

    getDataOne=(data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({ myData: data });
    }

    render(){
        const firstComponent = <ChildComponentOne onGetSearch={this.getDataOne} />            
        const stateValue = this.state.myData
        return (
            <div>
                {firstComponent}
                <ChildComponentTwo dataOne={this.props.location.state.searchData} dataTwo={stateValue} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent;
```

rendering the first child before the return will give some time to update the state.

Comment: try logging the state variable before the return and see if the state is set at that point

Comment: then I think the issue is with the second component

Comment: If I pass a string (just a word) through that dataTwo, it shows in the second component, but the state data isn't showing.

Comment: oh, then try to get the state value to a constant and then pass it to the child component. I updated the answer

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I guess I will have to try and restructure my code in another way, thanks for the responses man.

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran could you clarify from which place you're calling `onGetSearch` callback from the first component? I mean is it happens in the constructor or lifecycle method or in reaction to user action?

Comment: Although I've restructured my components. To answer your question, I'm calling the onGetSearch callback from a submit event, it's a form, and I'm getting the form data here in the parent component.